# MySQL - PHP SELECT Table With Calculated Relation

Tags: mysql

I have this Table:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
|  username  | exam_code | module | value | percentage |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    1   |   60  |      -     |
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    2   |   80  |      -     |
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    3   |   70  |      -     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    1   |   60  |      -     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    2   |   70  |      -     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    3   |   90  |      -     |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

i want to input myself (with php POST), the percentage of the modules.
for example, if i put `module 1 = 50%`, `module 2 = 35%`, `module 3 = 15%`
(total will be 100)

it will turn the previous table into:

```
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
|  username  | exam_code | module | value | percentage |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    1   |   60  |     50     |
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    2   |   80  |     35     |
|    aaaaa   |     x     |    3   |   70  |     15     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    1   |   70  |     50     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    2   |   70  |     35     |
|    bbbbb   |     x     |    3   |   90  |     15     |
+------------+-----------+--------+-------+------------+
```

*until this line, I can do this with PHP*

What I want to ask, how to turn this table (after inputted percentage fields) into this

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  username  | module 1 | module 2 | module 3 |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    aaaaa   |     30   |    28    |   10.5   |
|    bbbbb   |     35   |    24.5  |   13.5   |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

(explanation)

```
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  username  | module 1 | module 2 | module 3 |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
|    aaaaa   | (60x50%) | (80x35%) | (70x15%) |
|    bbbbb   | (70x50%) | (70x35%) | (90x15%) |
+------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

how to `SELECT` (not create table) to get this table, just using MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT username, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN module = 1 THEN value*percentage/100 END) as module1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN module = 2 THEN value*percentage/100 END) as module2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN module = 3 THEN value*percentage/100 END) as module3
FROM tablename
GROUP BY username
```

[SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d17e/1)